# Convert Perl Executable to Perl Script

Tags: perl

> Hi All,
>
> I have converted the perl script to perl executable using `perlcc` .So
>   Now I want to convert perl executable to perl script. Is there any way
>   to do this...?

Comment: Also asked on http://www.perlmonks.com/?node_id=926150

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

I remember compiling my first C program in 1992, `cc -o code.c code.c`, and then wondering where my source-code disappeared to. (If this is what you did, restore from backups. No backups? Well, think about doing backups.) No, it's not possible. You might be able to work out the algorithm by studying the binary very *very* carefully, but it's unlikely to help. It would probably be easier to rewrite the application from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

best way to convert perl and all script to exe stand alone file use htwoo project in sourceforge.net

download project link :

http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/htwoo/Hadi-Kiamarsi-HTWOO-2.rar?r=&ts=1363693006&use_mirror=freefr

download tutorial movie :

http://youtu.be/UQVuFQX4uOo